# Access server-side data in client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Attempting to create a webapp in google-script that will allow users to pick a sheet, name and create a calendar.

I thought I could just push all important information parsed as json to client-side, and then just use scripts there to access the different parts of template.data to then later call the google-script code to create the calendar. But I can't even throw alerts with the name of whatever I'm clicking.

So what I expected to happen with code below was clicking any list item would just return the text inside `<li>` but every list item gives the alert "undefined"

My doGet() in code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  // Parse all sheets available and set as element to template
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ui");
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);

  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  var json = [];
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    json.push(getScheduleAsJSON(sheet));
  });
  template.data = json;  
  return template.evaluate();
}
```

My ui.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function getName(){
        alert(this.InnerHTML);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="SheetList">
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){?>
        <li onclick="getName();">
          <?=data[i].name;?>
        </li>
      <?}?>
    </ul>
    <ul id="NameList">
      <li onclick="getName();">foo</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit 1:

So looks like I goofed when even trying the HTML part, changing these bits.

```
<li onclick="getSheetName(this);">
  <?=data[i].name;?>
</li>

function getSheetName(item){
  console.log(item.innerHTML);
}
```

Would still want to be able to somehow access the array of jsons computed server-side without having to call google.script.run each function.

Edit 2:

Think I've identified what I'm looking for; PropertiesService. I have still no clue as how to implement and actually access the data I assume I've stored in it. Everything I've tried so far has always yielded the same "undefined" results. Currently storing the whole json as a string in my script properties, can't access anything on the console.log however so not sure at all whether this actually is a step forward or not.

So currently added to my doGet():

```
var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
properties.setProperty("schedule-data", JSON.stringify(data));
```

And this function being called with google.script.run.onsuccesshandler.myfunc():

```
function getProperties(){
  var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  return properties.getProperty("schedule-data")[0].name;
}
```

Logger.log(json[0].name) returns "March 2017" so still at a total loss as to why I'm not getting anything on the html side of things...

Comment: If you want code to run after the Web App has loaded, then use `window.onload = thisFunctionRunsAfterLoad() {console.log('it did actually run')}`  I would not use the alert function to determine what is actually happening in your browser code.  Use `console.log()` statements for the browser, and `Logger.log()` statements for .gs scripts.  In Chrome hit the f12 key to open the console in the browser.  It looks like you are trying to create a file picker or something like a file picker.

Comment: Yes maybe something like a file picker, but my current issue is I just want the json data I parsed already server-side to be available to my client-side scripts. And here I am stuck even just accessing the innerHTML of any items.

Comment: I've provided a working example of creating a Web App with a bulleted list from an array of data.  The example excludes getting data from the spreadsheet.  The answer is meant to provide a basic starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `data` which needs to be loaded into the HTML with a "scriptlet":

```
<? var data = getData(); ?>
```

You can see an example in the documentation at the following link:

[Calling Apps Script functions from a template](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#calling_apps_script_functions_from_a_template)

### ui.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      window.onload = function myOnloadFunc() {
        console.log('The Web App has loaded')
        google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(funcToRunOnSuccess)
         .getData();
      }

      window.funcToRunOnSuccess = function(returnedData) {

        window.mySpreadsheetData = returnedData;
        console.log('window.mySpreadsheetData: ' + window.mySpreadsheetData)
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Anything</div>

    <? var data = getData(); ?>

    <ul id="SheetList">
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){?>
        <li onclick="getName();">
          <?= data[i]; ?>
        </li>
      <?}?>
    </ul>

    <ul id="NameList">
      <li onclick="getName();">foo</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Code.gs

```
function getData() {
  var arrayOfJSON,allSheets,data,html,ss,template;
  //ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);

  //allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  //arrayOfJSON = [];

  /*allSheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    Logger.log('sheet: ' + sheet)
    json.push(sheet);
  });
  */
  arrayOfJSON = ['one','two','three'];
  return arrayOfJSON;
}

function doGet() {
  var html,template;

  template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ui");  
  html = template.evaluate();

  return html;
}
```

Comment: Say the data is an array such as [{name=foo, id=123, contents={alice=[], bob=[], carl=[]}}], now I'm currently listing each name, what I want is onclick to access the contents and populate another `<ul>` but can't even access any part of the structure.

Edit (misclicked enter): If I could just set the contents of json as a variable accessible to scripts client-side with something like: "var data = <?=getData();?>;"

Comment: Okay.  You need to store the JSON data in the browser.  There are a couple of ways that you can do that.  1) Put the data into the browser's `window` object.  See updated answer: `window.mySpreadsheetData = <? var data = getData(); ?>;`  You could also put the data into session storage.  `window.sessionStorage`

Comment: I keep getting the error "expected function but recieved ;" when trying your newest answer

Comment: Sorry, try:  `<?  window.mySpreadsheetData = getData(); ?>; console.log('window.mySpreadsheetData: ' + window.mySpreadsheetData)`

Comment: window not defined, and not sure how I should go about defining that in my code.gs

Comment: I've updated the answer.  When the Web App loads, the code will need to call a server function, separate from the server code that runs when the template is being evaluated.  You need to run `google.script.run` and use a success handler.

Comment: Works like a charm. Managed to get the same thing going using properties but somehow this felt more clear.